# Roof over sunken porch repair or replace

Tags: roofing, porch

The concrete pad of my porch has sunken and cracked over the years and I’m currently looking to replace it. My question is am I going to have to do a tear down and replacement of the porch roof? The pad has sunken a few inches and is tilted forward.

Comment: Picture would help.  It will depend on how the roof is supported and how good of condition the roof is in.  With the pad sinking, quite a bit of base work will probably be needed.

Comment: We have no understanding of how the roof relates to the concrete. Please revise to add a better description and/or photos. Good answers depend on details.

Answer (score 1):

If the roof is attached to the house on one end, it can most likely be supported temporarily. Then the pad is re-poured with proper footings for the permanent supports.

This can be tricky and is best left to someone who has the experience and know-how to do the job safely and correct.